# How do I put the text inside the circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I created a program that is supposed to display 50 circles on the screen each having a number from 1-50 on it but the numbers are only appearing on the first row not the rest. I want each number to be sort of.. fixed inside the circles so that later on when I call one of the numbers, it appears along with its circle. This is my code.

```js
var i;
var texts = [];

for(i=1;i<=50;i++){
  texts[i]=i;
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('mindMap');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var w = 50;
var h = 50;
var r = 30;

for (var i = 1; i <=texts.length; ++i) {
  ctx.beginPath();

  if((i>=10)&&(i<=20)){
    ctx.arc(w-630, h+70, r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.font = '12px Arial';
    ctx.textAlign  = 'center';
    ctx.fillText(texts[i], w-630, h+70);
  }
  else if((i>=21)&&(i<=31)){
    ctx.arc(w-1400, h+140, r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  }
  else if((i>=32)&&(i<=42)){
    ctx.arc(w-2170, h+222, r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  }
  else if(i>=43){
    ctx.arc(w-2940, h+300, r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  }
  if((i>=1)&&(i<=9)){
    ctx.arc(w, h, r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = '#C0B7EE';  
  ctx.fill();
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.font = '12px Arial';
  ctx.textAlign  = 'center';
  ctx.fillText(texts[i], w, h);
  w += 70; 
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mindMap" width="800" height="800" style="border:1px solid red">
  <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed a lot of the code, your explanations didn't say why it would be needed. If that is not what you wanted, add more information about the objective.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('mindMap');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '12px Arial';
ctx.textAlign  = 'center';

var w = 50;
var h = 50;
var r = 30;

for (var i = 1; i <= 50; ++i) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(w, h, r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#C0B7EE';  
  ctx.fill();
  
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillText(i, w, h + 5);
  
  w += 70;
  if (i % 11 === 0) {
    h += 70;
    w = 50;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mindMap" width="800" height="800" style="border:1px solid red">
  <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it appears as if the `w` variable isn't getting reset after each line. When you spawn the circles, you already fixed it with the `w-1400` for example. You never did that on the text. You also need `h+=70`. Or it won't go down to the next line.